# How to access FetchError class in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, fetch-api

NodeJS 18 has an experimental support for `fetch` https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/globals.html

`fetch` function throws `FetchError` instances which I need to analize in `try-catch` with `instanceof` check... Unfortunately, `FetchError` class is not exposed in the global space of NodeJS!

I understand the API is "experimental" but, seriously, is there a way to access that class? Ideal answer will compile in TypeScript as well

P.S. one workaround is `error.name == "FetchError"` but I'm still curious about the class. Why it's not exposed?

Comment: The `FetchError` class is not exposed in the global scope of Node.js

Answer (score 1):

I agree it's painful to not have a simple way to analyze errors.

What I'm doing **in TypeScript** when `fetch()` is throwing and I target a specific code error (in this case `ENETUNREACH`):

```
import { FetchError } from 'node-fetch';

try {
    await fetch('...');
} catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof Error && (error.cause as FetchError)?.code === 'ENETUNREACH') {
        ...
    } else {
        throw error;
    }
}
```